# Why do the clang sanitizers not link the sanitizer runtimes when linking shared libraries

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, address-sanitizer, ubsan

Right in the docs for the address sanitizer (https://releases.llvm.org/7.0.0/tools/clang/docs/AddressSanitizer.html), it states that:

> When linking shared libraries, the AddressSanitizer run-time is not
> linked, so -Wl,-z,defs may cause link errors

That appears to be true not only for ASAN, but UBSAN as well. This turns out to be particularly inconvenient with UBSAN, since the `vptr` sanitizer can introduce new typeinfo dependencies between libraries (lots of details in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-49798).

I'd really prefer to build with `-Wl,-z,defs` for our UBSAN builds. And I can actually make that work with a ubsan build so far as the compile goes, by manually injecting things like `-lclang_rt.ubsan_standalone-x86_64` into the link lines for the shared libraries.

But that leaves me with a nagging question: *why* doesn't the `clang` link driver do this automatically when linking shared libraries, per the explicit documentation? It clearly *could* do it, since it already does it for programs which get the runtime automatically. The fact that it explicitly doesn't leads me to wonder if doing so is somehow problematic.

- Is forcing the `ubsan` runtime library onto the link line for all shared libraries a bad idea for some reason?
- Does it undermine the effectiveness of the sanitizer somehow?
- Is there some other horrible downside I'm not seeing?

Comment: I used `-fsanitize=undefined,null,address,bounds,bool,enum` and I don't have to do anything special.

Comment: @Eljay -  Are you also linking shared libraries with `-Wl,-z,defs`? The question is explicitly about linking shared libraries when using the sanitizers, and why when building such libraries they don't include the runtime automatically, which makes use of `-Wl,-z,defs` impossible.

Comment: Sorry acm, outside of my experience.